# $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(x+1)}x=1$ proof

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\ln(x+1)}x=1$$
How can I prove this without the substitution $t=\frac1x$? I came nowhere using epsilon–delta definition.

Comment: Depends on your definition of $\ln$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $t=\frac{1}{x}$ , because ln is continous function :

$\lim_{x\to0} \, $$\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}$

$ \lim_{t\to\infty } \,tln(1+\frac{1}{t} $

$ \lim_{t\to\infty } \ln (1+\frac{1}{t})^{t}$ =ln $e$ =1

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$, then
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f^{\prime}(0)=1$$

Comment: Can you really do that ? mixing up as h goes to zero and x going to zero .

Comment: This is a valid definition of the derivative, yes. And the variable is just a placeholder, you can call it whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [De l'Hospital's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{[\ln(x+1)]'}{x'}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{(x+1)'}{x+1}}{1}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x+1}=1
$$

Comment: Its good method but we are not supposed to use l'Hospital.

Comment: ok! I did that because you didn't specify that in the OP. you just excluded substitution.